# How to fix pandas to_sql append not appending one item out of 2000?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with 2000 rows and 3 columns of type Int, String, and String respectively. I'm trying to write a program that creates a table and appends my CSV file rowsxcolumns into the table. It all seems to work, except for a single item. The item's first and third column are appended, but the second one is null.

No errors are shown on the console, and I have tried printing the data to the console before calling the to_sql function and it shows the one missing item just fine. My CSV file also uses a delimiter. That item was at first not correctly formatted and so after delimiting all of my rows, I had to specifically delimit that single row by itself - I'm thinking that this could have caused the problem? All of the other rows and columns are perfectly fine.

Here's my code:

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

connection = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
c = connection.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE test(val1 int, val2 varchar(255), val3 varchar(255))''')

connection.commit()

col_names = ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
read_clients = pd.read_csv(r'thefile.csv', encoding='utf-16', names=col_names, sep='\t')

read_clients.to_sql('test', connection, if_exists='append', index = false, schema='test')

connection.commit()
```

No messages are printed to the console.

Comment: Does the read_clients DataFrame look as it should before the read_clients.to_sql()?

Comment: @braintho Yes, I print the data frame and it correctly displays the data under the specified columns. Even when I print only the one item that I'm having trouble with, it looks fine. It's just after the to_sql() function call. Everything works fine except for that one item...

Comment: Then you don't have a problem with the csv or the DataFrame.  The issue must be related to the table definition.  Do the datatypes in your DataFrame correlate to the datatypes in your sqlite table?  Do you have any strings that are longer that 255 characters?  That's where I would begin looking.

Comment: @braintho wow that totally makes sense because val3 for that one item is more than 255 characters, I didn't even think of that. However, val2 is only 2 characters where as val3 is the one that's 532 characters. Is val3 maybe making val2 void?

Comment: Actually, I just tried making val3 1000 characters and it still didn't work for that one item's val2.

Comment: I figured it out. My string for val2 is "NA". Python interpreted this as NaN - a null value. smh! This gave me so much trouble lol

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it.  I still confused on why you couldn't see the NaN's in the column before the to_sql() was called.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I actually did have NaN before the to_sql() was called, but I thought that it was the same value as my string because they looked so similar.

Comment: I get that.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the value of the string that was missing was "NA". Python apparently translates this to a null value! Here's how I fixed it:

```
read_clients = pd.read_csv(r'thefile.csv', encoding='utf-16', names=col_names, sep='\t', na_filter=False)
```